# how to get real time output from subprocess popen python script when using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

test.py:

```
import os,subprocess,sys

cmd=['python', 'hellodude.py']

os.environ["PYTHONUNBUFFERED"] = "1"

process = subprocess.Popen(
    cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)

while True:
    out = process.stdout.read(1)
    if out == '' and process.poll() != None:
        break
    if out != '':
        sys.stdout.write(out)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

hellodude.py:

```
import time
import requests as req

print 'hey'
time.sleep(5)
print 'cheers'
```

i installed pip requests and requests[security]
If you comment out requests import, it works.. How to fix it?
Using python 2.7 on linux or windows if that matters.

Comment: So maybe few things: 
1.  when running directly the script that should be subprocess completes normally ? 
2. `requests` isn't in the python standard library. Are You sure You got it in `site`
3.  what does this subprocess returns ?

Comment: it prints nothing, yea its pip installed

Comment: totally had a different python in path, which didn't have requests installed, if i forwarded stderror, i would have seen it